# Single page application using express and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. How to create single page applications with reactjs and express without webpack. Searched in google, found single page apps with webpack, Need some suggestions.

Comment: Have you actually tried googling before asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = ["eda3a923d17", "3a1593a3b3b", "afdedf6dcbd", "3c86c0bc427"];
JSON.stringify(array.map(function(id) { return { id: id }; }));
// => "[{"id":"eda3a923d17"},{"id":"3a1593a3b3b"},{"id":"afdedf6dcbd"},{"id":"3c86c0bc427"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert Array to JSON

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```